# How to get multiple values from a ditcionary

Tags: python-3.x

Hey guys I have a exam next week, and I need to get better with dictionaries. I have this code and I cant figure out how to go about it. Our class are writing code with python language. version 3 (Python 3)

Like say I have a dictionary, and I want to return true if that dictionary has like two or more keys that refer to the same value and false otherwise.

```
>>> duplicate({'a': 9, 'b': '9', 'c': 7, 9: True})
False
>>> duplicate({'a': 9, 'b': 9, 'c': 7})
True
'''
```

I gave it a shot but I dont think its right.

```
def duplicate(dict1):
    for a key, value in dict1.items():
       dict1[value] = key
    return dict1
```

like I dont get how to find those two keys VALUES.

please help out I would really appreciate it. Any hint or any solution would be better.

Comment: Why is it false in the first case? There are two keys (`a` and `b`) that both have the same value. By your description, shouldn't the algorithm return `True` here?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: In the first dictionary 'a': 9 is an integer while 'b': '9' is a character/string.

Comment: @Ma3x: Thank you for clarifying. Didn't see that before!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quick and dirty:

```
def has_dupes(x):
    z = list()
    for val in x.values():
        if val in z:
            return True
        z.append(val)
    return False
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

simple enough.

```
def duplicate(A): return len(A) != len(set(A.values()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def duplicate(x):
    return len(x.values()) > len(set(x.values()))
```